# height 100% and min-height 100%

Tags: html, css

i need the third and fourth rectangle to have the same position but fill all the height remaining in % and I cant change the min-height:100% on the body, html. using css, html ,code below.

```css
  html, body{ min-height: 100%; } 
  * { margin: 0;}
  
  div>div { 
     float: left;
     width: 50%; 
 }  
  .rectangle-one{
  height: 100px;  
  background-color: red;
 }
  .rectangle-two{    
  height: 100px;  
  background-color: black;
 }
  .rectangle-third{  
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
 }
  .rectangle-fourth{ 
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  
<body>
  <div > 
    <div class="rectangle-one"></div>
    <div class="rectangle-two"></div>
  </div> 
  
  <div > 
    <div class="rectangle-third"></div>
    <div class="rectangle-fourth"></div>
  </div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display:table should do:

```css
  html, body { 
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
    } 
  * { 
        margin: 0;}
  body {
        display:table;  
        table-layout:fixed;
    } 
  body>div {
        display:table-row;
    }
  div>div { 
     display:table-cell;
     width: 50%; 
 }  
  .rectangle-one{
  height: 100px;  
  background-color: red;
 }
  .rectangle-two{    
  background-color: black;
 }
  .rectangle-third{  

  background-color: green;
 }
  .rectangle-fourth{ 

  background-color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  
<body>
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="rectangle-one"></div>
    <div class="rectangle-two"></div>
  </div> 
  
  <div > 
    <div class="rectangle-third"></div>
    <div class="rectangle-fourth"></div>
  </div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it doesn't have the min-height on body and html

Comment: @Noobest , there is **no point** when table display is used, it will expand as much as you feed it . just test it :) that's the magic of it and why i proposed you this method. By the way , html,body {min-height:100%;} will only work on html, body has no height reference to use. i wish you lots of fun learning CSS :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap the second row columns within a parent with calculated height will do the work.

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
}
div>div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.row-first {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}
.row-second {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  width: 100%;
}
.rectangle-one {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.rectangle-two {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
.rectangle-third {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}
.rectangle-fourth {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<body>
  <div class="row-first">
    <div class="rectangle-one"></div>
    <div class="rectangle-two"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-second">
    <div class="rectangle-third"></div>
    <div class="rectangle-fourth"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sounds good but calc have some compability issues with ie and android.